BackdropInvertBrush for .NET 8.0
I'm looking for something like the BackdropInvertBrush that can be used in a project that aims WPF in .NET 8.0.
With the help of Google I found this site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.media.backdropinvertbrush?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.1
It describes a brush that does exactly, what I'm looking for (inverting whatever color is "behind" a control), so that I can put a string on top of a user defined background image and the string will always be readable.
But unfortunately the mentioned NuGet package "Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Media" can't be used with .NET 8.0, at least it gets declined because it's incompatible, when I'm trying to install the package.

Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp is for UWP, not WPF anyway.

BTW, it's possible what you're after already exists, just under a different name. In the graphics world, I see people tend to prefer more exact terms like "XOR blending mode" instead of the vaguer  term "inverted colors" . When I googled for "WPF XOR blend mode" I found some things that pointed me towards WPF's built-in pixel-shader support, which you can use to implement XOR blending (and others, like Screen, Multiply, Hard Light, etc - same as Photoshop, in fact).

There are also other approaches to improve text readability on arbitrarily colored backgrounds, see e.g. How to: Create Text with a Shadow.
